# tell if two android bluetooth devices are no longer actually connected to bluetooth socket

Tags: android, bluetooth

in my app I have a service that runs a thread that reads/writes to a `BluetoothSocket`. If i explicitly close the connection on one device, the other device's thread throws an `IOException` immediately. This is ideal because I can tell when the connection has been lost.

However, when the devices get extremely far apart (way past the range of bluetooth) the thread does not seem to notice. It throws no exceptions, and seems to be in its normal connected state. The socket is only written to when an sms is received. So perhaps when no sms has been received, no attempts to read/write to the socket have occured, and therefore no exceptions have yet been thrown.

How can I tell when to close the connection if the devices have become too far apart? Perhaps using a timer to periodically attempt to write to the socket would force an exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth tries to maintain connections even when far apart by increasing its transmitter power. Your best bet is to make a timer to see if they are no longer communicating.

Comment: and how to see that they are connected or not?

Comment: A combination of ping time out and `bluetoothSocket.isConnected()`.